# What are efficient way to handle corner issues

Tags: python

I have a script that run every week. For this, my week start from tuesday and end on monday (except for beginning of the year and end of the year). Below is code I wrote:

```
end_date = datetime.utcnow().date()
idx = (end_date.weekday()) % 7
end_date = end_date - timedelta(idx)
start_date = end_date - timedelta(6)
```

This is working fine except at the first week of the year and last week of the year.

For first week, it should start from `01-01-2020` (dd-mm-yyyy) and end on `06-01-2020`.

Similar error would come at last week of year. Is there any addition that can be done to logic to capture corner cases?

**EDIT**: If I run above piece the **start date at beginning of year become 31-12-2019**. I would like it **to be 01-01-2020**. Similarly, for the last week of year, start = 29-12-2020 and **end should be 31-12-2020. (But, above piece give different end date)**.

Comment: and what exactly is your problem? If you are having problems writing the corner cases then yes, we can help.

Comment: Answered. Please check edit.

Comment: Why not use cronjobs for this?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to clarify how you want to handle the corner case? Most importantly, why it is a corner case in the first place? The rule "from tuesday and end on monday" is a perfectly valid rule that works across year boundaries. Adding the extra rule to split the "week" on new-year introduces the corner case in the first place, treating two partial weeks as two weeks.

Answer (score 1):

You should checkout the function relative delta

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
date_end = date + relativedelta(days=7))
```

It automatically adds or substract and deals with corner dates

In your case, I think this works best:

```
date_max = datetime.date(end_date.year, 1,1)
start_date = max(date_max, end_date - timedelta(6))
date_min = datetime.date(start_date.year+1,1,1)-relativedelta(days=1)
end_date = min(date_min, start_date+timedelta(6)
```

Comment: See edit and tell me what you think